# Encoding strings to and from base-64

Tags: c#, string, base64

I'm trying to encode some strings back and forth from base-64 string and I'm having truble to get the right result.

```
string text = base64string.... //Here I have a base-64 string.
byte[] encodedByte = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
string base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedByte);

if (text == base64Encoded) //If the new encoded string is equal to its original value
    return base64Encoded;
```

I have tried my ways to do this and I don't seem to get the right result. I have tried both with `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` and `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`

What could be the problem? Does anyone have a proper solution?

Comment: Ok reading through your code you are taking a base64 string and then encoding it to base64 then comparing the encoded string to the orignal?

Comment: Why are you starting from the encoded form?  You could try doing the encoding first from plaintext, then decode it.  Or are you trying to implement the encoding/decoding algorithm yourself?

Comment: @Brian - Yes thats what I´m doing.

Comment: @Erik, remember, `text` will not match with `base64encoded` as `base64encoded` is the "garbled" contents of `text`, :D

Comment: why the downvote.

Erik I think you see the problem now.  I think what you want to do is pass the original unencoded string to Convert.ToBase64String(encodedByte); then compare the result to your original encoded string to see that they match.

Comment: @Erik, that is not what you are doing; you are comparing the *unencoded* `text` string with the *encoded* `base64Encoded` string. Obviously they are not the same; look at them in the debugger.

Answer (score 12):

```
string text = base64string.... //Here I have a base-64 string.
byte[] encodedByte = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
string base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedByte);
```

You are double encoding the string.  You begin with a base64 string, get the bytes, and then *encode it again*.  If you want to compare you will need to begin with the original string.

Comment: S - I know that. What I want is to encode a base-64 string to another format and then encode back to base-64 again, just to see if the result of the encoding hasnt lost any of the data. I know it´s a silly operation, but I want to do it anyway.

Comment: @ErikLarsson: Well base64 already guarantees that you will not lose data, so I don't see the point.  However, if you know what I am telling you... then what is the question?  Obviously you will not get the same thing when you encode a string again and again.  Start with the original string, encode it, decode it if you really want to check.

Answer (score 6):

If `text` is a base-64 string, then you are doing it backwards:

```
byte[] raw = Convert.FromBase64String(text); // unpack the base-64 to a blob
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw); // assume the blob is UTF-8, and 
                                         // decode to a string
```

which will get you it as a `string`. Note, though, that this scenario is only useful for representing unicode text in an ascii format. Normally you wouldn't base-64 encode it if the original contents are `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert whatever it is that you need in Base64 into a Byte array then use the FromBase64String and ToBase64String to convert to and from Base64:

```
Byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(myBase64String1);
myBase64String2 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```

myBase64String1 will be equal to myBase64String2. You will need to use other methods to get your data type into a Byte array and the reverse to get your data type back. I have used this to convert the content of a class into a byte array and then to Base64 string and write the string to the filesystem. Later I read it back into a class instance by reversing the process.

Answer (score 0):

You have the encoding code correctly laid out. To confirm whether the base64-encoded string is correct, you can try decoding it and comparing the decoded contents to the original:

```
var decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64encoded);
var compareText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decodedText);

if (text == compareText)
{
    // carry on...
    return base64encoded;
}
```