# Base 64 encoding in wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, base64

I have a string that i would like to encode in base64. I would also like the final encoding to be saved in a string.

In iOS would be :

```
- (NSString *)encodeCredentials
{
    //string to be encoded
    NSString *deviceUUID = "34543647yrgsav635Chbvcew4f56v"
    NSData *plainTextData = [deviceUUID  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String = [plainTextData base64EncodedString];
    //i return the encoded string
    return base64String;
}
```

How would that be in wp7 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding strings to base-64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878449/encoding-strings-to-base-64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For encoding:

```
public string Encode(string str)
{
   return Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
}
```

For decoding:

```
public string Decode(string str)
{
   return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(str));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this method on the net, hope it can help :

```
static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
{
  byte[] toEncodeAsBytes
        = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
  string returnValue
        = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
  return returnValue;
}
```

In wp7 you will probably be forced to replace ASCIIEncoding by UTF8Encoding or Encoding I do not remember well but Intellisense does, it's in System.Text anyway.

Here is the doc for System.Convert.ToBase64String : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx