# Encode string to Base64 in android without special character?

Tags: android, string, base64

I am trying to encode the string data in Base64. I am using this code :

```
Byte[] url_base64=repl.getBytes("UTF-8");
String con_base64=Base64.encodeToString(url_base64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Via this code i am getting special characters like ("/","\","\n") etc. How to ignore these special characters in base64 encoding in android.

Please help me if you have any idea about it.

Comment: Please show a fully working example so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding strings to and from base-64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878449/encoding-strings-to-and-from-base-64)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you want, but

```
Base64.encodeToString(url_base64, Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

will replace "\" with "_"